# Number of integers points on a sphere with radius 25

Tags: geometry, number-theory

How to find the number of integer coordinates of the set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=25^2\}$ . Do we have any solution for more generaliized problems in higher dimensional spheres with any radius?

Comment: Your title suggests you want the radius to be $25$, but the sphere equation you give in your problem statement is for a sphere of radius $5$.  Which are you looking at?

Comment: See Hirshborn, On representations of a number as a sum of three squares - http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X9800288X#

Comment: There has been a lot of investigation of the number of representations of a given integer $n$ as a sum of $k$ squares for various values of $k$. There are formulas for some small values of $k$, formulas which generally depend on the prime factorization of $n$. The Hirschhorn paper is also at http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper63.pdf

Comment: Have you had a chance to track down this paper?

Comment: Earth to user90533: Come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange [showed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem) that any integer can be written as the sum of four squares. So, for spheres in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 4$, this theorem tells us that we have at least one point with integer coordinates, since we may always find $a, b, c,$ and $d$ such that

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = k,$$ for any positive integer $k$ (in your problem, you want $k = r^2$, where $r$ is the radius of your sphere).

It isn't necessarily the case that all of $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are distinct and non-zero, but in what follows, I'll assume they are. Things get messy when they aren't, and need to be handled on a case-by-case basis.

In $\mathbb{R}^4$, this guarantees us at least $4!$ integer points on a given sphere, since we can permute the coordinates (i.e., if $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ works, then $(2, 1, 4, 3)$ must also work, etc). Further, if $(a, b, c, d)$ works, then we can make any entries negative, and there are $2^4$ ways to assign negative signs to a $4$-tuple $(a, b, c, d)$. Thus, when $n = 4$, we have at least $2^4 \cdot 4! = 384$ integer points on our sphere, guaranteed by Lagrange's four-square theorem (again, assuming $a, b, c$ and $d$ are distinct).

If we're in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n > 4$, can still apply this four-square theorem, since we can pad any sum of 4 squares with zeros. This means that we'll have at least $2^4 \cdot \frac{n!}{(n - 4)!}$ integer points on a sphere whose radius is the square root of an suitable integer (whose decomposition into a sum of four squares uses four distinct non-zero integers). The $2^4$ comes from assigning signs to our non-zero coordinates, and the $\frac{n!}{(n-4)!}$ comes from permuting the non-zero coordinates.

This is simply a lower bound on the number of integer coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n \geq 4$, in certain situations, but hopefully it's relevant to you.